# Greatest Lower Bound in $\mathbb{R}$ as a corollary of the LUB?

Tags: real-analysis

I can assume as fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is an ordered field in which every non-empty subset that is bounded above has a least upper bound.

My question is whether I can also assume as fact that every non-empty subset that is bounded below also has a greatest lower bound. I'm trying to show that if $A,B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, and $A,B \neq \emptyset$, then there exists a least upper bound for $A$ (I've proven this), and a greatest lower bound for $B$ (this is what I'm currently concerned with).

Any tips, or helpful definitions?

Comment: @bof fixed, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: If $A\subseteq\Bbb R$ is bounded below, then $-A=\{-a:a\in A\}$ is bounded above.

Alternative HINT: Let $B$ be the set of lower bounds for $A$. $B$ is bounded above, and its supremum is ... ?

Comment: I'd delete my redundant answer, but MSE does not provide me with a "delete" button. Is that because I'm an "unregistered user"? Is "100% free, no registration required" a bait-and-switch deal?

Comment: @bof: Yes, that’s the reason: unregistered users cannot delete their answers. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-register) is from StackOverflow, but I believe that it describes the situation here as well.

Comment: Wow, I just learned that I can't even **ask** a question here. Wish I'd known that 82 answers ago. Live and learn. Adios, y'all.

Comment: @bof: Why not register? You’ve posted some good answers.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, if every nonempty set that is bounded above has a least upper bound, then every nonempty set that is bounded below has a greatest lower bound. I know of two different ways to prove this.

1. Suppose $B$ is nonempty and bounded below. Then the set $-B=\{-x:x\in B\}$ is nonempty and bounded above, so it has a least upper bound, call it $u$. Then $-u$ is the greatest lower bound of $B$.
2. Never mind, just read Brian's answer!